# No visible @interface in my main

Tags: objective-c

i can not figure out why I am getting the error *No visible @interface for 'StockHoldings' declares the slector*

I have googled it and looked thru here and I am still confused could some one point me in the right direction. Thank you.

StockHoldings.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHoldings : NSObject
{
    //three instance varibles
    float purchaseSharePrices;
    float currentSharePrices;
    int numberOfShares;
}

@property float purchaseSharePrices;
@property float currentSharePrices;
@property int numbeOfShares;

-(float)costInDollars; //purchaseSharePrice * numberOfShares
-(float)valueOfShares; //currentSharePrice * numberOfShares
```

StockHoldings.m

```
#import "StockHoldings.h"

@implementation StockHoldings

@synthesize purchaseSharePrices, currentSharePrices, numbeOfShares;

-(float) costInDollars
{
    return ([self purchaseSharePrices] * [self numbeOfShares]);
}

-(float) valueOfShares
{
    return ([self currentSharePrices] * [self numbeOfShares]);
}



@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHoldings.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"Hello\n");

        StockHoldings *stock1 = [[StockHoldings alloc]init];
        [stock1 currentSharePrices:1.0];
        [stock1 purchaseSharePrices:2.0];
        [stock1 numbeOfShares:3];






    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The most important part of the error message is missing: the selector name.

Comment: Forget about it: you are calling the getter-named method to set the value. Use `[stock1 setCurrentSharePrices:1.0]` instead ;)

Answer (score 4):

The setter method name for properties is `set[PropertyName]`, so your code should probably read like this:

```
StockHoldings *stock1 = [[StockHoldings alloc]init];
[stock1 setCurrentSharePrices:1.0];
[stock1 setPurchaseSharePrices:2.0];
[stock1 setNumbeOfShares:3];
```

At your preference, you may also want to use the dot syntax instead:

```
StockHoldings *stock1 = [[StockHoldings alloc]init];
stock1.currentSharePrices = 1.0;
stock1.purchaseSharePrices = 2.0;
stock1.numbeOfShares = 3;
```

And finally, you may want to fix that `numbeOfShares` typo (missing an R for "number").

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the setters properly. For a `@property (weak) id data` once synthesized the setter method would be like `[self setData:@"foo_bar"]`. And getter method will be like `[self data]` The default name for a setter method is `set<Property>`

So in your case :

```
[stock1 setCurrentSharePrices:1.0];
[stock1 setPurchaseSharePrices:2.0];
[stock1 setNumbeOfShares:3];
```